# IOS Charts bar chart inconstant results

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, bar-chart, ios-charts

I am using danielgindi/Charts library. In my main view controller I have table view with 3 prototype cell. One of them is for bar chart, second one is for line chart and third one is for pie chart. There are also 3 dequeue reusable cell method and charts configure methods are inside of them. When I first execute application all my bar charts are drawn without any problem. However, when I add new charts or when I scroll (I am not sure but I think one of them lead weird problem) bar chart view looks weird as it shown below image.[image: Weird one]

[image: Normal one]

It is shown like second one when I first execute program but after some scrolling or adding new charts it looks first one. Every data set cover x axis. Following is my configureBarChart method.

```
func configureBarChart(xTitle: IndexAxisValueFormatter, index: Int, chartData: BarChartData, chartType: String) {


barChartView.data?.setDrawValues(false)
barChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
barChartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false
barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1)
barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false        

barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xTitle
barChartView.xAxis.labelCount = index


barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false

barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
barChartView.xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = true
barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
let leftAxisFormatter = NumberFormatter()
leftAxisFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1

barChartView.leftAxis.spaceTop = 0.35
barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
barChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false


barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false

var groupSpace = 0.0
var barSpace = 0.0
var barWidth = 0.0

if (chartData.dataSetCount == 1) {
groupSpace = 0.3
barSpace = 0.0
barWidth = 0.7
} else if (chartData.dataSetCount == 2) {
groupSpace = 0.3
barSpace = 0.05
barWidth = 0.3
} else if (chartData.dataSetCount == 3) {
groupSpace = 0.25
barSpace = 0.05
barWidth = 0.2
} else if (chartData.dataSetCount == 4) {
groupSpace = 0.2
barSpace = 0.05
barWidth = 0.15
}

let groupCount = index
let startYear = 0

chartData.barWidth = barWidth;
barChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = Double(startYear)
let gg = chartData.groupWidth(groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)

if (chartType == "clustered") {
barChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(startYear) + gg * Double(groupCount)
chartData.groupBars(fromX: Double(startYear), groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)
} else {
barChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(startYear) + 1 * Double(groupCount)
}


barChartView.setScaleEnabled(false)

if xTitle.values.count >= 10 {
barChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(12)
} else {
barChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(Double(xTitle.values.count))   // When too many data comes I limit it so data's are not covering each other.
}
}
```

I am also using that bar chart for grouped bar chart that is why there is some barSpace and barWidth code. What could be the reason of changing behavior of chart and how can I fix it ?

Edit: Here is my cellForRowAt method and getting data of bar chart

```
if MainGrafikVC.barChartDataArray[indexPath.row].dataSetCount != 0 {
                    cell.barChartView.data        = MainGrafikVC.barChartDataArray[indexPath.row]
                    cell.configureBarChart(xTitle: MainGrafikVC.xTitleArray[indexPath.row], index: MainGrafikVC.barChartDataArray[indexPath.row].getDataSetByIndex(0).entryCount, chartData: MainGrafikVC.barChartDataArray[indexPath.row], chartType: Servisler.servisListesi[MainGrafikVC.indexler[indexPath.row]].chartType)
            }

if x10.count > 0 {
var barChartEntry10 = [BarChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<x10.count {
let value = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(x10[i]) ?? 0.0)
barChartEntry10.append(value)
}
let bar10 = BarChartDataSet(values: barChartEntry10, label: "10")
bar10.colors = ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom()
                dataSets.append(bar10)
            }
let data = BarChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
MainGrafikVC.barChartDataArray.append(data)
```

I think the **problem** is about **setVisibleXRangeMaximum** because when I comment it everything looks same. However, I need to set visible x axis what could be alternative of it?

Comment: You mean your three charts aren't arranged in correct order when you scroll the table?Or the data is covering each other?

Comment: As you can see from the picture data is covering whole x axis when I scroll it.

Comment: May I know where you put chart data set and Chart setup code in Cell ?

Comment: @CodeChanger I have edited question could you please take a look?